# master slave replication in database

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication

How I can avoid stale data to be read from slaves?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant was: how to prevent stale data being read by a slave after the master has updated data?

You can measure the replication lag between your master and slave; it should ideally be a very small value like 500 milliseconds. For PostgreSQL there is a tool called pgbench which may be useful.